# Best Practice for retrying page.goto, page.waitForNavigation etc. in puppeteer/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer, tor

I'm trying to scrape some web pages in the TOR network, using Puppeteer and the tor package (`apt install tor`).
Probably due to the nature of TOR connections sometimes I get a timeout.
In addition, I'm new to asynchronous programming in JavaScript.

Usually I have a try-catch-construct like these:

```
await Promise.all([
  page.goto(url),
  page.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
  }),
]).catch((err) => { logMyErrors(err, true); });
```

or

```
let langMenu = await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(@class, ".customer_name")]/ancestor::li').catch((err) => { logMyErrors(err, true); });
```

But I think often one or more retries would help to finally get the desired resource. Is there any best practice to implement retries?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Possibilites are to increase the timeout and/or set a maximum number of retries before canceling and then repeating the request while its timeouting (?). So there is no law and you have to decide based on your goal/system/resources etc.

Comment: Yeah, but in case of multiple retries I'm not sure about how to implement the retries without producing a mess of nested code. Or is it just too simple? How would you do 3 retries of the above ```let langMenu```example?

Comment: I have added an answer, is it working?

Comment: I tried to integrate it in my code but didn't manage to get it work. But this will rather be due to my still insufficient knowledge concerning asynchronous JavaScript programming. I was able to integrate Thomas Dondorf's more compact suggestion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend this rather simple approach:

```js
async function retry(promiseFactory, retryCount) {
  try {
    return await promiseFactory();
  } catch (error) {
    if (retryCount <= 0) {
      throw error;
    }
    return await retry(promiseFactory, retryCount - 1);
  }
}
```

This function calls the `promiseFactory`, and waits for the returned Promise to finish. In case an error happens the process is (recursively) repeated until `retryCount` reaches `0`.

**Code Sample**

You can use the function like this:

```js
await retry(
  () => page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(@class, ".customer_name")]/ancestor::li'),
  5 // retry this 5 times
);
```

You can also pass any other function returning a Promise like `Promise.all`:

```js
await retry(
  () => Promise.all([
    page.goto(url),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' }),
  ]),
  1 // retry only once
);
```

**Don't combine await and catch**

Another advice: You should not combine `await` with `.then` or `.catch` as this will result in unexpected problems. Either use `await` and surround your code with a `try..catch` block or use `.then` and `.catch`. Otherwise your code might be waiting for the results of a `catch` function to finish, etc.

Instead, you use `try..catch` like this:

```js
try {
  // ...
} catch (error) {
  logMyErrors(error);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Workflow

- Define a retry function
- run retry function if promise rejects
- control retries with retryCount

#### Concise copy+paste solution:

```js
const GotoWithRetry = async (page, url, retryCount = 2) => {
  if (retryCount < 0) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to navigate to ${url} after 3 retries.`);
  }
  await Promise.all([
    page.goto(url, {
      timeout: 120 * 1000,
      waitUntil: 'load',
    }),
    page.waitForResponse((response) => response.ok(), { timeout: 8000 }),
  ]).catch(() => {
    GotoWithRetry(page, url, retryCount - 1);
  });
};
```

- [More concise solutions](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2460) that you can adapt for Puppeteer
- Credit goes to [Menelaos Kotsollaris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373465/menelaos-kotsollaris) for this solution

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of retrying without pyramid of doom.
Im no ES expert though and there may be some new async/await features which could make the code more cleaner but this works for now:

```
function retry(callback, retries) {
    let tries = 0;

    function tryRequest() {
        tries++;
        return callback().catch(e => {
            logMyErrors(e);

            if (tries < retries) {
                return tryRequest();
            }
        });
    }

    return tryRequest();
}

const logMyErrors = console.log;


retry(() => {
    console.log("retry");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Emulate some rejections here
        if (Math.random() > 0.2) {
            throw new Error("Something went wrong."); 
        }

        resolve("Success");
    });
}, 10).then((result) => {}, (rejected) => {});
```

The function `retry` accepts a callback which **must** return a promise. `callback` is executed until either the Promise finishes (resolves, rejects) or the amount of `retries` is reached.